# sqlserver stored procedure comment lines in Chinese is garbled

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

[image]

The Red text should be Chinese but now they are garbled.I want to know why and how to solve it.this is in sqlserver2008.Look forward to your reply!

Comment: This is a shot in the dark, but what's the default collation for your database?

Comment: @BenThul, comments are treated as normal text and so don't think has anything to do with collation here.

Answer (score 0):

In SSMS, go to:

‘Tools‘ -> ‘Options‘ -> ‘Environment‘ -> ‘Fonts and Colors‘ -> Select ‘Text Editor’

and then you can change Font type.

Comment: AFAIK, This will not help